# How to deal with Cronbach's alpha "data must either be a data frame or a matrix" error?

Tags: r, statistics, alpha, psych

I have imported my data. The columns in question only contain numbers and `NA`.

I try to compute the `cronbach's-alpha` between my 4 variables as follows (there are more variables in the dataframe):

```
library(psych)

alpha (df$column1, df$column2, df$column3, df$columns4)
```

I get the following error:

> Data must either be a data frame or a matrix

What could be the problem / the solution?
This is probably very basic. But so am I. Thanks in advance!

Greetings from Berlin
Paul

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you share a sample of your data frame?

Comment: The [documentation for alpha](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.12/topics/alpha) looks like it expects a data.frame or matrix of data. You can't just pass in four columns as separate parameters. You should check the help file to see what parameters a function expects and find examples of its correct use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one work around

```r
df <- data.frame(df$column1, df$column2, df$column3, df$columns4)
alpha(df)
```

See `?alpha` for detail.
The input `alpha` expects is `a data.frame or matrix of data, or a covariance or correlation matrix`. You can create a dataframe out of the desired columns and pass that to `alpha` with additional arguments if you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked. But I fell like I should have learned something here. How is what I entered not a data frame?

Comment: Packages expect input in certain way. It is not your fault but it just means one needs to read package documentation.